# Crop raster with polygon in R: Error extent does not overlap

Tags: r, image-processing, crop, raster

I want to crop a raster stack using a polygon shapefile i made in ArcGIS, however I get error that extent does not overlap.

First I create the raster stack:

```
test1 < stack("C:/mydir/test1.tif")
```

define projection

```
myCRS <- test1@crs
```

then read shapefile

```
myExtent <- readShapePoly("C:/mydir/loc1.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=myCRS)
```

Crop

```
myCrop <- crop(test1, myExtent)
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

I have searched for a solution, but i only find that projection can be the problem, however they are definetly both in the same CRS:

```
> test1$test1.1
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  4  bands)
dimensions  : 10980, 10980, 120560400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 6e+05, 709800, 5690220, 5800020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\mydir\test1.tif 
names       : test1.1 
values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)

> myExtent
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 499386.6, 517068.2, 6840730, 6857271  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 2
names       :    Shape_Leng,    Shape_Area 
min values  : 67444.6461177, 283926851.657 
max values  : 67444.6461177, 283926851.657
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is pretty self explanatory.  Your extent do not overlap...  here how to check it:

```
library(raster)
ext.ras <- extent(6e+05, 709800, 5690220, 5800020)
ext.pol <- extent(499386.6, 517068.2, 6840730, 6857271)


plot(ext.ras, xlim = c( 499386.6,709800), ylim= c(5690220,6857271), col="red")
plot(ext.pol, add=T, col="blue")
```

I've created extent object from data in your question.  You see one  extent in the top left corner and the other in the bottom right.  Have you tried reading both files in QGIS, you could probably easily see it.

[image]

If they really are suppose to overlap, than I would suspect the way you read your shapefile. Instead of

```
myExtent <- readShapePoly("C:/mydir/loc1.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=myCRS)
```

use :

```
library(rgdal)
myExtent <- readOGR("C:/mydir","loc1.shp")
myExtent <- spTRansform(myExtent, CRS(proj4string(test1)))
```

Comment: thank you, i used readOGR() and spTransform() as you suggested and it worked perfectly

Comment: This is probably because, with your call `myExtent <- readShapePoly("C:/mydir/loc1.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=myCRS)`, you were giving it a projection that wasn't its real one.  There is a big difference between stating the projection and transforming the projection.  When you play with projection, let the function read the projection from the file, than always transform using the appropriate function (`spTransform`, `projectRaster`  or `gdalwarp`)