# Match extents of two rasters in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, devtools, extent

I am trying to use the 'grainchanger' package in R to aggregate finer resolution raster to a coarser one.

I have 10km grid outlines of the UK, which I have converted from shapefile to raster.

I also have a land cover map of the UK in raster form.

I need to look at the land cover %s in each 10km square of the land cover map.

When I try aggregating this using the grainchanger package, I get the following error:

```
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap
```

I think this is because my 10km grid raster is squares which the land cover map does not fill.

How can I change the extent of the land cover map so it matches the 10km grid raster?

This is my code:

```
library(raster)

# continuous landscape
show_landscape(cont_ls)

# load the coarse resolution raster
g_raster <- raster("raster.tif", package = "grainchanger")

show_landscape(g_raster)

# direct aggregation using range
dda <- nomove_agg(coarse_dat = g_raster,
              fine_dat = cont_ls, 
              agg_fun = var_range)
#> aggregation assumes all cells are rectangular
#> ● set `is_grid = FALSE` if coarse_dat is not a grid
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message suggests that you could have an issue with projection, but it's hard to know without having more information.

You could check the extents do overlap with

```
library(raster)
ext.ras <- extent(6e+05, 709800, 5690220, 5800020)
ext.pol <- extent(499386.6, 517068.2, 6840730, 6857271)


plot(ext.ras, xlim = c( 499386.6,709800), ylim= c(5690220,6857271), col="red")
plot(ext.pol, add=T, col="blue")
```

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887129/10434025).

If they do not overlap and you expect them to you can use `spTransform()` to change the projection.